# Passing numpy array to function giving type error

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Not sure why I keep getting an error when I try to plot a bar chart.

```
 def plotBar(x,y):
    plt.bar(x, y, width=1, align='center', color='plum', edgecolor='firebrick',linewidth=1)
    plt.show()
```

In main I am calling the function like this:

```
x1=np.arange(1,101)
y1=np.arange(50,151)

classname.plotBar(x1,y1)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

`TypeError: plotBar() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: You need to declare plotBar as: `def plotBar(self,x,y):` since it seems to be a class method of classname

Comment: `classname.plotBar(x1,y1)` It seems like you've tried to create a class that has a method called `plotBar`. When creating a method, the first variable (often called `self`) is the class instance. You can try to change `plotBar(x,y)` into `plotBar(self,x,y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I declared your function as a **static** method in a class:

```
class Xxx:
    @staticmethod
    def plotBar(x,y):
        plt.bar(x, y, width=1, align='center', color='plum',
            edgecolor='firebrick', linewidth=1)
        plt.show()
```

The next correction is that both arrays have to be of equal length,
so I changed definition of *y*, so that it also has **100** elements:

```
x1 = np.arange(1,101)
y1 = np.arange(51,151)
```

(previously it had **101** elements).

Then I called it:

```
Xxx.plotBar(x1,y1)
```

and got a picture.